# Assigning a reference to a struct

Tags: c++, reference

I have a variable `ntot_sols` who's final value isn't known when my object is constructed.

Consequentially I want to store a reference to the variable instead of the value since it's subject to change.

I think the following code will do it.

```
struct ItemWeighter {
   int nsols;
   int ntot_sols;

   ItemWeighter(int _nsols, int& _ntot_sols) {
     nsols = nsols;
     ntot_sols = _ntot_sols;
   }
   
   float weight() {
      return nsols / float(ntot_sols);
   }
};
```

But I'm surprised that `ntot_sols` is type `int` and not `int &`. How does the variable know that it's a reference?

Comment: `ntot_sols` **is not** a reference.

Comment: If I put in `int & ntot_sols` then the linter gives me an error saying that ntot_sols wasn't initialized

Comment: You would need to put it in the initializer list.

Comment: If you have a data member that is a reference, you need to initialize it through the constructor.  The constructor parameter must be a reference and you should be using an initializer list.

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds like a bad idea. What’s the lifespan of the referred variable? What’s the lifespan of your structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the assignment operator to bind a reference.  It has to be bound when first created.  For a class member variable, this means you have to do it in a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor); the body of the constructor is too late.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>


class foo {
private:
    int& x;
public:
    foo(int& other_var) : x(other_var) { }
    ~foo() { }
    void print_x() { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    foo my_foo(a);
    my_foo.print_x();
    a = 10;
    my_foo.print_x();
    return 0;
}
```

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9Kbj8dre8).  It prints out:

```
5 
10
```

Note that such code, where your object holds a reference to another variable created elsewhere, can be risky.  It is up to you to make sure that the referenced `int` has a lifetime at least as long as the `foo` object.  It can be easy to get this wrong, and the compiler won't help you.  Consider for instance:

```
foo make_a_foo() {
    int a = 7;
    foo f(a);
    return f;
}

void other_func() {
    foo g = make_a_foo();
    g.print_x(); // undefined behavior!
}
```

Here `g.x` is a reference to the local variable `a` from `make_a_foo()`, whose lifetime ended when `make_a_foo()` returned.

It may be better after all to make `x` an ordinary `int` member variable, instead of a reference, and call a setter function to update its value when needed.

Comment: How come I have to use an initializer list instead of defining it in the constructor function? Is a reference similar to const somehow?

Comment: @financial_physician: That's just how the language works.  The idea is that it should never be possible to have a reference that isn't bound to some object.  If you could start executing the body of the constructor before initializing the reference, then you could potentially access it before initializing, e.g. `foo(int& a) { std::cout << x; x = a; }`.  That should be impossible and prevented at compile time. [...]

Comment: @financial_physician:  Instead of making the compiler analyze the statements in the body, it is easier to put the initializations before the body even starts, so that it is inherently impossible for the body to access an uninitialized reference.  It is a similiar situation with `const` members (there must never be a time when they are uninitialized) and with members that are classes (there must never be a time when they have not been constructed).

Comment: Makes sense, but then I'd argue that any variable should be initialized in the initializer list and not just the references

Comment: @financial_physician: Yes. that is good practice.  For an ordinary variable like `int`, it's optional, because you are allowed to have such variables uninitialized until you assign to them later.

Comment: Or, if you want to use a reference it's usually best to make it `const int& x` to prevent unexpected side effects.

Comment: @financial_physician Yes, it's always a good idea to initialize your variables. With most variables you can do that at definition, like `int x{};`. But due to the nature of a reference it must be *bound* when the object is constructed. That's why you need to do it in the constructor.